# Adding new nodes relative to TreeView selected node

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

My question is about adding new node to the selected node.  For example I have my treeview nodes and when I selected 1 node and click button (`addCategory`) I have to add a node to the same level. If I selected 1 node and click button (`addSubCategory`) I have to add a node to the sub level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fact it could change a bit if you are in windows forms or web forms I guess but **pseudo-code** for what you ask is this:

**AddCategory**

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Add("my new category");
```

**AddSubCategory**

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add("my new sub category");
```

of course check SelectedNode and Parent for `null` before doing this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you click an Node and click the addCategory button you can take the parent of that node. Then add a node to the parent. If the parent is null (root item selected) just add an item to the TreeView. If the addSubCategory button is clicked you add a Node to the selected Node.

**Edit:**

In following code 'treeView1' is the Name-property of the TreeView. In your code this could be something else, so change accordingly. Same goes for 'textBox1':

```
protected void categoryButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
    {
        var nodeText = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null)
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(nodeText));
        else
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(nodeText));
    }
}

protected void subCategoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nodeText = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        treeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(nodeText));
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeView1.SelectedNode != null )
            if (RadioButton1.Checked==true)
            {
                string ParentNode;
                ParentNode = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
             
            }
    
      
    }

ı have this code .but ın the program  " TreeView1" and "ParentNode" underlined:S for what ı didnt understand

Comment: Can you explain clearer..treeview1 is not the name of Treeview?? if not Can you expalin how can ı describe..It is first time for me to use treeview?

Comment: Every Control you put on your Form, or your Form itself, has a Name-property to identify it. What is the Name-property of YOUR TreeView? In my code-example the Name is 'treeView1'.

Comment: <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowLines="True" 
           ExpandDepth="0" 
            ExpandImageToolTip="" >
         <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="Gray" />


        </asp:TreeView>

this is my source code of treeview.And Website not form application

Comment: Now I get it. You have an ASP.NET application and not a WindowsForms application. Then indeed your controls are identified by ID and not Name.. :) Check my edited answer again, make sure the ID is corrected to the ID of your TreeView! :)